# Show $2x - 1 - \sin (x)$ has exactly one real root.

Tags: calculus, curves

**I have the following solution to the above problem:**

Let $f(x)=2x-1-\sin(x)$

Observe, $2x-1, \sin(x)$ are continuous functions, hence by arithmetic of continuous functions $f(x)$ is continuous $\forall x$.

$f'(x)=2-\cos(x)$, hence $f'(x)>0$, $\forall x$ and hence $f(x)$ is increasing $\forall x$.

Observe $f(0)=-1<0$ and $f(\pi)=2\pi-1>0$ hence since $f(x)$ is continuous and increasing $\forall x$ there is exactly one real root.

*I'm wondering if my solution would be considered acceptable and if there is an alternative way to go about solving this problem. Thanks!*

Comment: Your proof looks good. One thing to note, is that you can make $cos(x)$ into $\cos(x)$ by adding \ before the cos in LaTex. Also, depending on how in depth you want to get, you could always put in $f(2)=3-\sin(2)\geq 2>0$ so that you don't have to compare $2\pi$ and $1$. Of course, this is a minor quibble and your overall proof is excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Υοur solution is perfect.

As a slightly different proof, you can prove that $f$ has at least one root, and if you assume that has more than one roots, then by Rolle's s theorem, would exist $y\in \Bbb{R}$ such that $f'(y)=0$

Thus $\cos{y}=2$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is **not** perfect. A function is not an expression. You can say that $2x-1,\sin(x)$ are continuous **in $x∈\mathbb{R}$**, but they are not functions. And $f(x)$ is not a function either. You should also have defined the domain of $f$. You can either say that $f$ is continuous on its entire domain (presumably $\mathbb{R}$), in which case you can just say "$f$ is continuous", or you can say that $f$ is continuous at every $x∈\mathbb{R}$. Do not use "$∀$" in the manner you are using it, because it is wrong. Either write the intended meaning in proper words, or use the proper syntax of first-order logic if you still want to use the symbolic form. These errors aside, your idea of using IVT is correct.